# iCloud backup nightmare

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, icloud

My app has in-app purchases downloaded from Apple. I store them on a folder I have created on my app's library, something like /Library/myFiles

These files must persist for the app to work. I cannot put them on caches because iOS will delete them and the user will have to download it all the time.

Even putting them inside Library, Apple is still nitpicking about it.

On their email they say my app is using 6MB of backup but I don't even see my app on the iCloud part of my device's iOS.

Do I still have to exclude such files from iCloud backup using addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes if your files are really very local and it is really not needed to be backed up with iCloud then please add "Do not backup" attribute for preventing backup to iCloud.

Please also look at the [Apple's File System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html).

> > Handle support files—files your application downloads or generates and can recreate as needed:
>
> - In iOS 5.0.1 and later, put support files in the    < Application_Home >/Library/Application Support directory and apply
>     the com.apple.MobileBackup extended attribute to them. This attribute 
>     prevents the files from being backed up to iTunes or iCloud. If you
>     have a large number of support files, you may store them in a custom
>     subdirectory and apply the extended attribute to just the directory.

Comment: OK, but this is really stupid because as far as I know iCloud will only backup files on documents directory. My files are not there.

Comment: OK, I have already applied the "do not backup flag" to them at this point, but are you telling me that I have to put them on /Library/Application Support? I have put them on /Library/myDirectory.  I am allowed to do that, right?

Comment: As long as you have the flag set you should be fine, but in theory it's better to put your directory under Application Support rather than the library directly.  iCloud does back up other things under Library.

Comment: FYI, I ran into a situation where I had to use the com.apple.MobileBackup extended attribute to exempt a subdirectory of Application Support from backup as well.